# How to remove validator on id field in wtforms

Tags: validation, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I have created sqlalchemy class and wtform Form from class.

```
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.orm import model_form
class ClientGroup(Base, BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'client_groups'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    sale = Column(Integer)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


ClientGroupForm = model_form(ClientGroup, Form, field_args={
    'name': {'validators' : [validators.Required(), validators.Length(min=5)]},
})
```

in app I have following code:

```
form = ClientGroupForm(request.form)
if form.validate():
    .. save data
```

When i send a new data to app its returns me validation error. ID must be an integer field.
But a new data hasn't any id.

Please, give me advice How can I use wtforms with sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 2):

Make it optional explicitly, by adding the following to the `field_args`:

```
'id': {'validators' : [validators.Optional()],
```

However, I think you should exclude the `id` field from the form completely:

```
ClientGroupForm = model_form(ClientGroup, Form, field_args={
    'name': {'validators' : [validators.Required(), validators.Length(min=5)]},
    exclude=['id'],
})
```